# "The operating system is not presently configured to run this application" Error when Running MAPI App

Tags: outlook, windows-10, mapi, office-2016

Thank you for your reply and comments.

Let me describe the situation more detailedly.

I use Visual C++ 2008 to write a small application that will invoke MAPI. I use MAPIStubLibrary to support both 32bit and 64bit MAPI. MAPIStubLibrary can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc963763.aspx#sectionSection2 . It works on other versions of Outlook and most of the systems. However, under Windows 10(32bit) with Office 2016(32bit) installed, when I execute the following statement to initialize MAPI:

```
MAPIInitialize(NULL);
```

I will get the above error message "The operating system is not presently configured to run this application". And there will be an unhandled exception raised from the function GetDefaultMapiHandle(), which is in StubUtils.cpp, part of the MAPIStubLibrary.

The exact line that cause the exception is:

```
hinstMapi = LoadLibraryW(wzPath);
```

It seems that MAPIStubLibrary is trying to load 32bit MAPI but fails. wzPath is pointing to olmapi32.dll instead of msmapi32.dll.

In the error message, if I click “OK” button in the error messagebox, the application will continue running without problems. However, the error message is still frustrating and confusing the users. Therefore, how to eliminate the error?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What line of code exactly causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you are either loading a wrong MAPI dll (e.g. olmapi32.dll instead of msmapi32.dll) or if your app is running in the compatibility mode (do you include a manifest?) and the MAPI system ends up patching wrong Windows API functions assuming an older version of Windows.